# Problemas implementando firebase en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, build.gradle

Estoy intentando implementar Firebase en mi app en Android Studio y después de sincronizar el build.gradle me aparecen dos errores diferentes:

**class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found** y **Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzv found in modules classes**

Este es mi build.gradle(app)

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Google
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

    ...
}
```

Ya intenté implementar firebase sin BOM pero sigue sin funcionar. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: la implementacion de firebase está bien, el error debe estar antes. `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'` creo que en esta línea falta una palabra despues de services

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Eso arregló el problema. Muchas gracias!